# Let images scroll up while multiple backgrounds are fixed

Tags: css, background

I want the three backgrounds to stay fixed while the images scroll up leaving the background header and other backgrounds in place.  With the code below it just scrolls down losing the background images up the page.

Edit: I've updated the jsfiddle with fixed position on the division tags, but now the images don't scroll.

https://jsfiddle.net/gknLstpt/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html>
<html>
<HEAD>
<style type="text/css">
body { background-image:url('http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/Background-2013.gif') ;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-color:black; overflow:none;}


.bgimg-paisley {
    background-image:url('http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/black-paisley-background.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    overflow:none;
    background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:fixed;    
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
}

.bgimgborder {
    background-image:url('http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/runner-for-paisley-test.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    width:720px;
        background-size: cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;    
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;

}

.imgpadding {
    padding-left:10px;
}

-->
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="bgimg-paisley" style="position:absolute;top:97px;left:0px;width:100%;">
     <div class="bgimgborder" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:200px;">
    <img class="imgpadding" border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg" width="700" >
    <div style="height:80px;"></div>

    <img class="imgpadding" border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg" width="700" >
    <div style="height:80px;"></div>
    <img class="imgpadding" border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg" width="700" >
    <div style="height:80px;"></div>
    <img class="imgpadding" border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg" width="700" >
    <div style="height:80px;"></div>
    <img class="imgpadding" border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg" width="700" >
     </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the "background header and and other backgrounds"? Which images do you want staying put and which should move?

Comment: I want all the background images to be fixed.  Only want the img tags to scroll up.  So the viewer is always seeing the header with the black background and white/gray border on the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Background-position: fixed` relates the background to its container, but doesn't keep the container itself from moving. To get e.g. a header to stay in the same place at all times, add `position: fixed` to the header itself. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: I updated by jsfiddle with the fixed position but now the images aren't scrollable.  I tried putting them in a seperate div that wasn't fixed with no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Didn't quite get me the solution but I'm getting closer thanks to the clarification.

Comment: Glad that's pointing you in the right direction! Don't hesitate for help if you hit another wall. p.s. For that next wall: I find with fixed and absolutely positioned elements the main thing is figuring out exactly what I'm trying to do -- that can sometimes take quite a while, but things open up once you get there

Answer (score 0):

Try this remove `class="bgimg-paisley"` from `div` and added it to `body`.

```
 <body class="bgimg-paisley">
    <div  style="position:absolute;top:97px;left:0px;width:100%;">
         <div class="bgimgborder" style="Position:absolute;top:0px;left:200px;">
        <img class="imgpadding" border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg" width="700" >
        <div style="height:80px;"></div>
        <img class="imgpadding" border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg" width="700" >
        <div style="height:80px;"></div>
        <img class="imgpadding" border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg" width="700" >
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/gknLstpt/4/

Comment: The scrolling effect works but I lose the header background in the body tag and the background on bgimgborder no longer shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the below link. Make position fixed for the background and top:0px;

https://jsfiddle.net/gknLstpt/5/

```
<body>
```

```
 <div class="bgimgborder" style="Position:absolute;top:0px;left:200px;">
<img class="imgpadding" border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg" width="700" >
<div style="height:80px;"></div>
<img class="imgpadding" border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg" width="700" >
<div style="height:80px;"></div>
<img class="imgpadding" border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/bride-and-bridesmaid.jpg" width="700" >

    </div>
     </body>
```

Comment: I might be adding to the confusion because my jsfiddle isn't showing the header.  There is three backgrounds setup.  The bar up top in the body tag.  The black background in the division tag and a gray border to appear beside the images in another division tag.  I would like them all to be fixed and only the img tag scroll.